# Iterate over if conditions

Tags: java

I need to check multiple conditions something like this:

```
if(condition1 && condition2 && condition3) {
    ...
}
```

However, the number of condition depends on the number of keys of a map. So, if the map has one value the "if" should be:

```
if(condition1) {
    ...
}
```

If the map has two keys the "if" should be:

```
if(condition1 && condition2) {
    ...
}
```

and so on.

My question is if there is any way to iterate the map and add conditions to the "if", something like:

```
for(String key : map.keySet()) {
    //Now how I add conditions in every iteration?
}
```

**Edit:**

I put an example of my code because I think I didn't explain my problem properly. I have this code:

```
public Integer count(String columnName1, String valueName1, String columnName2, String valueName2) {
    Integer toReturn = 0;

    results.first();

    for (RowResult result : results.getResults()) { 
        if(result.get(columnName1).equals(valueName1) && 
                        result.get(columnName2).equals(valueName2)) {
            toReturn++; 
        }       
    }   
    return toReturn;
}
```

This code only checks two columns and I want to improve it to check N.

```
if(result.get(columnName1).equals(valueName1) && 
    result.get(columnName2).equals(valueName2) ... &&
        result.get(columnNameN).equals(valueNameN)) {
    toReturn++;
}
```

So, I created a map where I put columns as keys and values to check as values. The new `count` method should be:

```
public Integer count(String columnName1, String valueName1, String columnName2, String valueName2) {
    Integer toReturn = 0;

    results.first();
    for(String column : map.keySet()) {
        for (RowResult result : results.getResults()) { 
            //I am stucked here with the if
        }   
    }   
    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: Does your condition vary for each key in map?

Comment: Why `for (RowResult result : results.getResults()) { for(String column : map.keySet()) { /* something */ } }` shouldn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you meant somthing like this

```
/**
 *criterias hold Map<FieldName,ExpectedValue>
 *
 */
boolean rowFitsTheCriteria(RowResult row,Map<String,String> criterias){
    boolean result = criterias.keySet().stream().allMatch(fieldName->row.get(fieldName).equals(criterias.get(fieldName)));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can use somthing like this if you have java 8

```
    Map<String,Boolean> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    boolean allMatch = myMap.values().stream().allMatch(value->value);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Read my edit because I think I didn't explain my problem properly

Answer (score 4):

Using a flag is one way.

```
boolean isTrue = true;
for(String key : map.keySet()) {
    if(!condition) {
        isTrue = false;
        break;
    }
}

if(isTrue) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Read my edit because I think I didn't explain my problem properly